# font settings ignored in kendo-ui for angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, kendo-ui

I have a kendo-ui (angular) application and all of my fonts are displaying as Times New Roman, which looks horrible.

I have created a reference to the kendo default scss file and tried overriding the $font-family variable (as specified [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/styling/theme-default/customization/)), but this seems to make no difference. Overriding other variables does seem to make a difference however.

**My styles.scss file:**

```
$font-size: 16px; //this works
$font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif; //this doesn't
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all";
```

**My html**

```
<kendo-textbox-container floatingLabel="Short Code">
<input kendoTextBox id="shortCode"   value="{{account.shortCode}}">
</kendo-textbox-container>
```

The input and the label both come through as Times New Roman

Comment: Have you tried to set `Tahoma` as `"Tahoma"`? Is it a default OS font or does it come from the web?

Comment: Yes I tried that, same result.And if I set it as font family for an element type it will work too. I really wanted to do it the "proper" way though